# solr tomcat java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, tomcat, solr

solr server sometimes crashed with tomcat error, I've got no idea for what's going on?

```
May 04, 2016 4:32:44 PM 

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke 

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:407)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:739)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: is it your full stack trace of exception?

Comment: yes, I couldn't find any details about what happened. with restarting the server, the server could run quite well before next crash